# Issue retrieving an integer using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring, cloud, microservices, resttemplate

I am currently learning spring cloud microservices and I follow a really simple example.

So I have 2 services 1 for `currency exchange` and 1 for `currency conversion`. those two services talk to each other using 'resttemplate', however, when I try to get an object from `currency exchange` service I get all fields apart from the integer one, which return `0`.

**Beans:**

**CurrencyExchange:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurrencyExchange {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "currency_from")
    private String from;
    @Column(name = "currency_to")
    private String to;
    private int convertionMultiple;
    private String environment;
```

**CurrencyConversion:**

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurrencyConversion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "from_currency")
    private String from;
    @Column(name = "to_currency")
    private String to;
    private int conversionMultiple;
    private int quantity;
    private int totalCalculatedAmount;
    private String environment;
}
```

**Controllers:**

**CurrencyExchange Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/exchange")
public class exchangeCurrencyController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private CurrencyExchangeService currencyExchangeService;

    @GetMapping("/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}")
    public CurrencyExchange exchangeCurrency(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to) {

        CurrencyExchange currencyExchange = currencyExchangeService.findByFromAndTo(from, to);
        String port = environment.getProperty("local.server.port");
        System.out.println(currencyExchange);
        currencyExchange.setEnvironment(port);

        return currencyExchange;
    }
```

**CurrencyConversion Controller:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/conversion")
public class CurrencyConversionController {
    
    @GetMapping("/currency-conversion/from/{from}/to/{to}/quantity/{quantity}")
    public CurrencyConversion getCurrencyConversion(@PathVariable String from, @PathVariable String to, @PathVariable int quantity) {

        HashMap<String, String> uriVariables = new HashMap<>();
        uriVariables.put("from", from);
        uriVariables.put("to", to);

        ResponseEntity<CurrencyConversion> responseEntity = new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:8000/exchange/currency-exchange/from/{from}/to/{to}", CurrencyConversion.class, uriVariables);

        CurrencyConversion currencyConversion1 = responseEntity.getBody();

        System.out.println(currencyConversion1);
        
        return new CurrencyConversion(currencyConversion1.getId(), currencyConversion1.getFrom(), currencyConversion1.getTo(), currencyConversion1.getConversionMultiple(), quantity, currencyConversion1.getConversionMultiple(), currencyConversion1.getEnvironment());
    }
}
```

I have 3 object in my data base.

```
id conversion_multiple environment currency_from currency_to
1         12               8000        AUS          ILS
2         65               8000        USD          ILS
3        424               8000        INR          ILS
```

**Web debuging log:

**ExchangeCurrency Class:**

```
2021-12-16 21:39:00.550 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/exchange/currency-exchange/from/USD/to/ILS", parameters={}
2021-12-16 21:39:00.551 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.in28minutes.microservices.currencyexchangeservice.controllers.exchangeCurrencyController#exchangeCurrency(String, String)
2021-12-16 21:39:00.552 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select currencyex0_.id as id1_0_, currencyex0_.conversion_multiple as conversi2_0_, currencyex0_.environment as environm3_0_, currencyex0_.currency_from as currency4_0_, currencyex0_.currency_to as currency5_0_ from currency_exchange currencyex0_ where currencyex0_.currency_from=? and currencyex0_.currency_to=?
2021-12-16 21:39:00.557 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select currencyex0_.id as id1_0_, currencyex0_.conversion_multiple as conversi2_0_, currencyex0_.environment as environm3_0_, currencyex0_.currency_from as currency4_0_, currencyex0_.currency_to as currency5_0_ from currency_exchange currencyex0_ where currencyex0_.currency_from=? and currencyex0_.currency_to=?
PrintCurrencyExchange{id=2, from='USD', to='ILS', convertionMultiple=65, environment='8000'}
2021-12-16 21:39:00.561 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-12-16 21:39:00.562 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [CurrencyExchange{id=2, from='USD', to='ILS', convertionMultiple=65, environment='8000'}]
2021-12-16 21:39:00.564 DEBUG 6648 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

CurrencyConversion Class**

```
2021-12-16 21:37:39.776 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/conversion/currency-conversion-feign/from/USD/to/ILS/quantity/1123123", parameters={}
2021-12-16 21:37:39.777 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.in28minutes.microservices.currencyconversionservice.controllers.CurrencyConversionController#getCurrencyConversionFeign(String, String, int)
2021-12-16 21:37:39.795 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] o.s.w.c.HttpMessageConverterExtractor    : Reading to [com.in28minutes.microservices.currencyconversionservice.beans.CurrencyConversion]
CurrencyConversion(id=2, from=USD, to=ILS, conversionMultiple=0, quantity=0, totalCalculatedAmount=0, environment=8000)
2021-12-16 21:37:39.798 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8] and supported [application/json, application/*+json, application/json, application/*+json]
2021-12-16 21:37:39.798 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [CurrencyConversion(id=2, from=USD, to=ILS, conversionMultiple=0, quantity=1123123, totalCalculatedAm (truncated)...]
2021-12-16 21:37:39.800 DEBUG 10736 --- [nio-8100-exec-9] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

when I print to console the response. I get

`CurrencyConversion(id=2, from=USD, to=ILS, conversionMultiple=0, quantity=0, totalCalculatedAmount=0, environment=8000)`

which shows String returning but int showing `0`.
help me understand this.

THANKS

Comment: how does the database table look like?

Comment: @JensBaitinger I have just edited my post with the structure of the db

Comment: Does hibernate fetch conversionMultiple with correct value ?

Comment: @roma2341 apparently it fetches it with value of `0`. I have no idea why since other fields are ok, which are all `strings`. maybe it has to do somthing with mapping?

Comment: Maybe because of camelcase

Comment: Look's like non-hibernate issue. You should have the same property mapping stretegy   at both services. Because one returns camelcase, but other wait snakecase or vice-versa

Comment: @roma2341 where exactly would you recommend me to make changes?

Comment: I don't know exactly what will help in your case. For example, we have 2 microservices and we have Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer  bean defined in each of them where propertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE) is enabled. You can google it. It will allow you to transfer same class over the network without loosing fields, because field e.g first_name will be tackled by both microservices like firstName and object value won't be null when you receive object at any of your services that have this property name configured. Maybe there are better naming stretegies

Comment: But Jens Baitinger is right, you should enable logging first of all to see response body before adding any configuration

Comment: @roma2341 Thanks for the informaton. Also I will edit the post with the `debug-logging`

Comment: You have conver<<<t>>>ionMultiple and conver<<<s>>ionMultiple which are different

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `@Column` configuration:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CurrencyExchange {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(name = "currency_from")
    private String from;
    
    @Column(name = "currency_to")
    private String to;
    
    @Column(name = "conversion_multiple")
    private int convertionMultiple;

    private String environment;
}
```

otherwise Spring does not know which column to load the data from as the field name does not match your column name.

Comment: I am still gettins `0` on the integers for some reason. maybe something in my code is corrupt?

Comment: probably activate the [debug log](https://javadeveloperzone.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-enable-debug-logging/) and check what data is loaded from the database and how it is mapped to your data class.